# Magento 2: Problem creating search request with REST API : V1/customers/search

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I'm trying to make a search request which returns all the customers, but the php script below returns :

```
[message] => %fieldName is a required field.
[parameters] => Array
    (
        [fieldName] => searchCriteria
    )
```

My PHP script :

```
<?php

$search = '
{
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "value": "%",
                        "condition_type": "like"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "current_page": 1,
        "page_size": 1
    }
}
';

$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$api = "rest/V1/customers/search";

$ch = curl_init("http://my.website.com/index.php/".$api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $search);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ".$token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);

print_r($result);

?>
```

What's wrong with this request ?

This other way to write this request works fine:

```
curl -X GET "http://my.website.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search? \
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=email& \
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%& \
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" -g
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed my issue this way :

```
<?php    

$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$api = "rest/V1/customers/search";

$json = '
{
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "email",
                        "value": "%",
                        "condition_type": "like"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
';
$j = json_decode($json);
$get_params = http_build_query($j);

$ch = curl_init("http://my.website.com/index.php/".$api."?".$get_params);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json", 
  "Authorization: Bearer ".$token,
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention at-least one searchCriteria because search Criteria is required field (for example:- /rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[sortOrders][][direction]=ASC).

Comment: I have add "sort_orders": [ { "field": "name", "direction": 1 } ] right after the page_size, but I still get the same error message. Also, the curl command works without sort_orders.

Comment: did you checked my code(use only searchCriteria[sortOrders][][direction]=ASC and check)

Comment: it is working for me....i got data also..

Comment: no need to mention all search criteria ..but we have to write at least one search criteria.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answers. My problem is about correcting the json in the question.

Comment: you have mentioned [message] => %fieldName is a required field. right?...my answer is related to this not sjon.